# FLUTTER : Firebase Real-Time Instant User Search

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been trying to make instant searches between users in my Firebase Real-time database for 1 week.
but I did not find any examples on the internet. There is no resource in a way that works completely.

my firebase database is like this;

```
-users
 -A4GFSsae6mnbvjyr52
   -name: ceyhun
 -BFSAreadfmnbvjyr58
   -name: mert
       ...
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mean an user searching for other user right?

I will show an example with ScopedModel:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return ScopedModelDescendant<UserModel>(
  builder: (context, child, model){
    return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      future: Firestore.instance.collection("users").getDocuments(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(!snapshot.hasData){
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        }else{
          var dividedTiles = ListTile //to show the users in tiles
              .divideTiles(
              tiles: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc){
                return doc.documentID != model.firebaseUser.uid ? UserTile(doc) : Container();
              }).toList(),
          ).toList();

          return ListView(
              children: dividedTiles,

          );
        }
      },
    );
  },
);
}
```

and then, in UserTile class, use the DocumentSnapshot as you wish.

Comment: I'm using Firebase Real-Time and I want the Instagram search page.